# Averaging a list of tuples from CSV file

Tags: python

For a personal project, I have a fairly large .CSV file of Apple's past stock data. I already have a function using the csv module to read this data and print out the date and the month's closing price:

Here's an example of the format of the tuple:

```
('2012-03-24' , '122.10')
```

What I am now looking to average the data for each month and regenerate the list of tuples.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm a beginning Python student.

```
def get_list_data(file_obj, column_number):    
    with open("table.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            data = row[0] , row[column_number]  #Data and column data
            list_of_tuples = tuple(data)
            print(list_of_tuples)

    return list_of_tuples

def average_data(list_of_tuples):  #This is where I am stuck
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: My apologies, I'll post what I have thus far.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) library for fast and efficient aggregation of time series.

Comment: I am missing your expected output and more sample input here still.

Comment: For what you are doing, I suggest you get the "SciPy" package, which includes a lot of cool stuff for statistics and graphing.  The easiest way to get SciPy is to get Enthought Python Distribution (EPD).  There are paid versions of EPD but for your needs, just get the free version.  NOTE: some people mentioned "numpy", and all the "numpy" stuff is included in SciPy, so if you get EPD you have numpy.  https://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php

Comment: In `get_list_data` you're resetting the value of `list_of_tuples` in the loop (for each row).  The return value of `get_list_data` is the tuple representing the last row of the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following steps:

1. First you need to convert the string from the second part of each tuple *('122.1')* into a float. You can do this with the `float()` method.
2. Second, you need to calculate the sum of all second parts of your tuple using the `sum()` method and [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
3. Divide by the length of the list that the function `len()` returns.

Code example:

```
def average_data(list_of_tuples):

    stock_data = [float(t[1]) for t in list_of_tuples]
    stock_sum = sum(stock_data)
    return stock_sum / len(list_of_tuples)
```

Example:

```
list_of_tuples = [('2012-03-24' , '122.10'), ('2012-03-25' , '117.30'), ('2012-03-26' ,  '126.9')]

print average_data(list_of_tuples)
>>> 122.1
```

Comment: Suzana, I really appreciate your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are teaching yourself python, go ahead and implement your own reader with `csv` and then work out the average calculations yourself.  It is an excellent exercise.

However, if you want to do less coding and spend more time on analysis, use
something like `pandas` (or at least `numpy`).  The `pandas` library excels at this type of data analysis.

The following ipython session shows how easy these types of calculations are with `pandas`.  (If you are not using ipython, then that's another tool
I strongly recommend that you learn.)  In this session, I read a CSV file
that contains Apple stock data.  The data file 'aapl.csv' looks like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2013-02-25,453.85,455.12,442.57,442.80,13276100,442.80
2013-02-22,449.25,451.60,446.60,450.81,11798600,450.81
2013-02-21,446.00,449.17,442.82,446.06,15970800,446.06
2013-02-20,457.69,457.69,448.80,448.85,17010800,448.85
2013-02-19,461.10,462.73,453.85,459.99,15563700,459.99
2013-02-15,468.85,470.16,459.92,460.16,13990900,460.16
2013-02-14,464.52,471.64,464.02,466.59,12688400,466.59
...
1984-09-14,27.62,28.50,27.62,27.87,8826400,3.13
1984-09-13,27.50,27.62,27.50,27.50,7429600,3.09
1984-09-12,26.87,27.00,26.12,26.12,4773600,2.94
1984-09-11,26.62,27.37,26.62,26.87,5444000,3.02
1984-09-10,26.50,26.62,25.87,26.37,2346400,2.97
1984-09-07,26.50,26.87,26.25,26.50,2981600,2.98
```

Import the pandas library:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
```

Read the data into a DataFrame, using the 'Date' column as the index:

```
In [2]: aapl = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Sort the index in ascending order:

```
In [3]: aapl = aapl.sort()
```

Take a look at the first few records:

```
In [4]: aapl.head()
Out[4]: 
             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                      
1984-09-07  26.50  26.87  26.25  26.50  2981600       2.98
1984-09-10  26.50  26.62  25.87  26.37  2346400       2.97
1984-09-11  26.62  27.37  26.62  26.87  5444000       3.02
1984-09-12  26.87  27.00  26.12  26.12  4773600       2.94
1984-09-13  27.50  27.62  27.50  27.50  7429600       3.09
```

Resample the data to monthly.  By default, the average of the daily values is used:

```
In [5]: monthly = aapl.resample('1M')

In [6]: monthly.head()
Out[6]: 
                 Open       High        Low      Close           Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                                              
1984-09-30  26.981250  27.333125  26.606250  26.738750   4807300.000000   3.007500
1984-10-31  25.035652  25.313478  24.780435  24.806957   5559408.695652   2.788696
1984-11-30  24.545238  24.782857  24.188095  24.236190   5749561.904762   2.724286
1984-12-31  27.060000  27.378500  26.841000  26.947500   6195360.000000   3.031500
1985-01-31  29.520000  29.855909  29.140000  29.253182  10353818.181818   3.289091
```

Plot the 'Close' column of the monthly data:

```
In [7]: monthly.plot(y='Close')
Out[7]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x45ff4d0>
```

Take a look at the 'Close' column:

```
In [8]: monthly['Close']
Out[8]: 
Date
1984-09-30    26.738750
1984-10-31    24.806957
1984-11-30    24.236190
1984-12-31    26.947500
1985-01-31    29.253182
1985-02-28    28.089474
1985-03-31    22.741429
1985-04-30    21.425238
1985-05-31    19.656818
1985-06-30    16.399000
1985-07-31    17.185455
1985-08-31    15.098636
1985-09-30    15.738500
1985-10-31    16.940000
1985-11-30    19.460000
...
2011-12-31    392.930476
2012-01-31    428.578000
2012-02-29    497.571000
2012-03-31    577.507727
2012-04-30    606.003000
2012-05-31    564.673182
2012-06-30    574.562381
2012-07-31    601.068095
2012-08-31    642.696087
2012-09-30    681.568421
2012-10-31    634.714286
2012-11-30    564.345714
2012-12-31    532.055000
2013-01-31    497.822381
2013-02-28    459.026875
Freq: M, Name: Close, Length: 342
```

Here's the plot generated by the `plot` method:
[image: Monthly average of 'Close']

Comment: Thanks, Warren! I think after this project is done I'll give your suggestion a try.